# Retrieve original value of an md5() variable

Tags: php

What's exactly the solution on how to retrieve the original value of a variable that undergoes md5 function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the original value of a MD5 function. This is only possible with something like rainbowtables or brut force. But there exists no way to get it with normal methods.